# Is a certain subgroup $S\leq G$ in the center of $G$, $S\leq Z(G)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

All groups considered are finite. Let $A$ be a group such that $A=A'\left<x\right>$, where $A'$ is the commutator group and $\left<x\right>$ is cyclic of order $p\in\mathbb{P}$. How can I prove that $\frac{A'}{\left[A',\left<x\right>\right]}\leq Z\left(\frac{A}{\left[A',\left<x\right>\right]}\right)$?
If needed, $A$ has only one maximal normal subgroup.

Comment: Good points:
1.
 $$[H,K]\unlhd\langle H,K\rangle$$
2.
 If $H\unlhd G$, $K\unlhd G$ and $K\subseteq H$ then $$H/K\subseteq Z(G/K)\Longleftrightarrow[H,G]\subseteq K$$

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true in $A = S_3 \times A_5$, for example, which has the unique maximal normal subgroup $A' = A_3 \times A_5$. We have $[A' ,\langle x \rangle ] = A_3$.

Comment: Derek, is it true that this example covers our hipothesis. I mean is it true that $A=A'\left<x\right>$?

Comment: Yes, $A'= A_3 \times A_5$ has index 2 in $A$ and, for $x$ we can take any element of order 2 in $S_3$.